# 2次元配列の特定の値をキーにしたHashを生成する方法

Tags: ruby

コード自体はかけたのですが、もう少し上手くかけないかと思い質問致します。

```
﻿﻿a = [[2014, 3], [2014, 5], [2015, 4], [2016, 2], [2016, 8]]
```

という配列から、配列の初めの要素に入っている年号をキーにした

```
{2014 => [3, 5],
 2015 => [4],
 2016 => [2, 8]}
```

という`Hash`を生成したく

```
a.group_by(&:first).map{|k, v| [k, v.map(&:last)]}.to_h
```

と書いたのですがかなりわかりにくい気がするので

```
h = {}
a.each do |k, v|
  h[k] ||= [] 
  h[k] << v
end
h
```

としました。できればもう少しすっきり書きたいのですがもっとシンプルな書き方はありますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

私もいつも悩みます。
その中でもやっているのは、デフォルト値を使うことで、key の判定を省略する方法です。

```
h = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
a.each do |k, v|
  h[k] << v
end
h
```

またこちらの記事 http://qiita.com/cuzic/items/a265f140fdff289d5c07#objecttap を読んでから、tap を使うことも多いです。

```
years_month_lists = {}.tap do |h|
  a.each do |k, v|
    h[k] ||= []
    h[k] << v
  end  
end
```

Comment: `tap`はこんな風にも使えるんですね。ただインデントを増やすのが好きではないのでデフォルト値を使う方法を使うことにします。

Answer (score 1):

`inject` を使うのはどうでしょうか。

```
a.inject(Hash.new([])){|h, (k, v)| h[k] += [v]; h}
```

Comment: hash の default 値に mutable な要素を使ってはいけない、と避けていましたが、非破壊メソッドを使うことで初期値としてだけ使うことができるんですね。目から鱗でした！

Answer (score 0):

```
h = a.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), res|
  res[k] ||= []
  res[k] << v
end

p h
```

Answer (score 0):

あくまで、`a`を破壊してもいいという前提ですが・・・

```
a.group_by(&:shift).each_value(&:flatten!)
```

Comment: なるほど、面白い方法ですね。ただ自分のレベルですと、後から読み返した時に何してるかパッとは理解できなさそうです…。